# sending form info to email

Tags: php, forms, email, submit

I have a form that sends info to php doc.  When testing, I submit and array displays but won't go to email address.

```
<?php require_once("/includes/fbcheader.php"); 
?>
<div class="comments">
     <h3> We Welcome All Comments </h3>
   <form action="/php/contact-send.php" method="post" 
                                            id="contact-form" class="form">
     <p class="input-block"> 
          <label for="form-name" >Name</label>
          <input type="text" value name="name" id="form-name" 
               autofocus placeholder="Please enter name" required>
          </p>
        <p class="input-block">
            <label for="form-email" >Email</label>
            <input type="email" value name="email" id="form-email" 
                 required placeholder="Please enter E-Address">
            <input type="hidden" value name="age" id="age">
        </p>
        <p class="input-block">
            <label for="form-subject" >Subject</label>
            <input type="text" value name="subject" id="form-subject"
                 required placeholder="Please enter subject">
        </p>
        <p class="textarea-block">
            <label for="form-message">Comment</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="form-message" 
                 cols="70" rows="10"></textarea>
        </p>
   <div class="clear"></div>
                <input type="hidden" name="firstname" id="firstname">
                <input type="submit" value="Send" id="form-submit">
                <p class="hide" id="response"></p>
            <div class="hide">
                <label for="spam-check">Do not fill out this field</label>
                <input name="spam-check" type="text" value id="spam-check">
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the sending php execute code

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Contact-Send</title>
</head>
 <body>
   <?php
      if(null!==($_POST["name"])) {
          $name = $_POST["name"];
         /* echo "Please enter 'Name'<br />"; */
      } else {
          $name = "";
      }
      if(null!==($email = $_POST["email"])) {
          $email = $_POST["email"];
          /* echo "Please enter 'E_Mail'<br />"; */
      } else {
          $email = "";
      }
      if(null!==($email = $_POST["subject"])) {
          $form_email = $_POST["subject"];
          /* echo "Please enter 'Subject'<br />"; */
      } else {
          $subject = "";
      }
    if(null!==($message = $_POST["message"])) {
        $message = $_POST["message"];
        /* echo "Please enter your message<br />"; */
    }   else {
        $message = "";
    }
    /*echo "{$name}, {$email}, {$message}";*/

  $email_from = '$Email';

  $email_subject = "New Form submission";

  $email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
                        "Here is the message:\n $message".

  $to = "me@myaddress.com";
   ?>
   <br>
     <?php
      $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

      $headers .= "Reply-To: $form_email \r\n";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

    header("thank-you.html");
   ?>

   </body>
  </html>
```

On submit I simply get the array displaying the content of the input fields

Comment: What do you mean "I simply get the array displaying the content of the input fields"?

Comment: Check the return value of the `mail()` function and your `From` header will cause the message to fail, you need to use double quotes there. None at all actually...

Comment: `value name` that'll cause some unexpected results.

Comment: @JohnConde - When I press submit the next page displays the input name and the content there of.  For example.  Array ([name] => Jonathan; [email] => JonDoe@abcsite.com; [age] =>  ;[subject] => test; ...

Comment: Then you have `<input type="hidden" name="firstname" id="firstname">` with no value and no reference for it, so I don't know why you're using that, and for `<input type="hidden" value name="age" id="age">` plus, what I said already about `value name`.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code. You can debug your code now.

Comment: You will see Undefined variable for `$email_from = '$Email';` once you use error reporting. Plus, undefined index, most probably.

Comment: I've removed the <input type= "hidden" name="firstname"....>  I've also added the err-reporting code without closing php tag and I get errors on each input field.  If I add closing tag to error_reporting I only get error on the particular line

Comment: I have to step out. Is there some way I can contact you directly.  TY

Comment: @jeroen - I've check the values in the array and all are correct.  The empty ones (or hidden) display no values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at your PHP code I see the following:

This:  `if(null!==($email = $_POST["email"]))` will fail because you are running a check against nothing.  it should be: `if(null!==($_POST["email"]))`.

You have an undefined variable here: `$email_from = '$Email';`  this will simply output "$Email".  It should be `$email_from = $email;` (as per your code).  However you are simply re-assigning the variable here which you dont really need to be doing at all.

Your [concatenating](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) the `$email_body` and `$to` address.

You `header("thank-you.html");` will fail because as per your code, output has already started here `<?php` (line 6).

You should be aiming for something closer to this for your **contact-send.php:**

```
<?php
      if(null!==($_POST["name"])) {
          $name = $_POST["name"];
         /* echo "Please enter 'Name'<br />"; */
      } else {
          $name = "";
      }
      if(null!==($_POST["email"])) {
          $email = $_POST["email"];
          /* echo "Please enter 'E_Mail'<br />"; */
      } else {
          $email = "";
      }
      if(null!==($_POST["subject"])) {
          $form_email = $_POST["subject"];
          /* echo "Please enter 'Subject'<br />"; */
      } else {
          $subject = "";
      }
    if(null!==($_POST["message"])) {
        $message = $_POST["message"];
        /* echo "Please enter your message<br />"; */
    }   else {
        $message = "";
    }
    /*echo "{$name}, {$email}, {$message}";*/

  $email_subject = "New Form submission";

  $email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
                "Here is the message:\n $message";

  $to = "me@myaddress.com";
    $headers = "From: $email \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    header("Location: thank-you.html");
   ?>
```

Remember to set `$to` to your email address!

Comment: Thank you @M.Doye for your time and consideration.  After cleaning up the some obvious mistakes and taking your advice above, I've gotten the code to work.  Have a few more questions concerning output format: ie setting font tags (<b>).  I know I will have to go out of php, but just wondering what the syntax might be.  Thanks again.

Comment: @JZeig1 no problem, glad to help.  You can find a really good example of how to do this [right here](https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/). This is a great example and its really quite easy, you will not have to change much of your code :-)